# How to access editing.view.getDomRoot() during plugin initialization?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to do something with the editing view DOM root that cannot be done via the engine view's API. For that, I need to access the DOM root in my plugin's `init()` callback.

It turns out, though, that the DOM root is created after plugins are initialized.

How can I access it from my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The UI is indeed initialized after plugins are initialized. See [these two lines](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/blob/d68db7723d18cf9c8c97d1608ea02182ccef37ee/src/classiceditor.js#L174-L175).

However, [`editor.ui`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorui-EditorUI.html) fires the [`#ready`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorui-EditorUI.html#event-ready) event, so this will work:

```
editor.ui.on( 'ready', () => {
    const domRoot = editingView.getDomRoot();

    // Do something with the DOM root...
} );
```